# Assigning operator function in variable

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a generic function for the `**` (unexisting) operator that would compute the left number to the power of the right number.

It works for 0 and and positive numbers, but i would like tackling negative numbers.

Several ideas come to mind, but I would like to try out storing the function of existing operators in a variable like so:

```
var operation = *
```

or

```
var operation = /
```

using `operation(a, b)` would do the same as `a*b` or `a/b`

Is such a thing possible in Swift?

Comment: I found out my basic exponents math was a bit shaky and using different operators would not change the issue.  Still it would be nice to know if storing the function associated with an operator to a variable is possible

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
var operation = *
```

But, you **CAN** do this:

```
var operation:(Int, Int) -> Int = (*)

operation(4,2) // -> 8
```

Because `*` has many overloaded types:

```
func *(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
func *(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
func *(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
func *(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
func *(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
func *(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
func *(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func *(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
func *(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
```

we have to explicitly specify which one.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was look for. I will try to find a solution that works for all numeric types types

Comment: Hmm.. I have no idea how to do that. Anyway, good luck to you!